# Is there anyway that I can get the running port?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I`d like to show in my React application the running port of the local server, is there any way to get it programmatically? The running port may defer if something is already running on the default port of create-react-app.

Comment: I don't think that part is  handled by or given access to React. create-react-app gives you a frontend build pipeline and comes with a live dev server but your react code wont be able to access server configurations. It might be possible with Next.js as it renders react on server.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

Comment: @AkashSarode makes sense, I thought there was some way to do something similar to the REAC_APP way to get env variables. Thanks anyway 

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app is a React toolchain, which packages some useful tools together to let you dive into development without any initial setup. Local development server is a part of that toolchain, it's only purpose is to serve static files your react app needs.

Sure, create-react-app lets you configure some options with environment variables but it is not meant to serve as backend for your react application.

You can achieve this with your own backend by writing an endpoint to get the server port but for the local server I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is not available since React App and Local server are running independently.
However, your server port will be available when you start the server. So you can have another API that will simply fetch the port of the server and that can be displayed accordingly.
Something like this on the server.

```
app.get('/server/port', (req, res) => {
  return res.json({port: server.address().port})
})
```

where your server is started at

```
const server = app.listen(20000)
```

In the react app, you can have the `fetch` request like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:20000/server/port')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
  // you will have the port no. in data.port
```

This will be helpful to you.

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to fetch the port with another API? Thanks in advance 

Comment: @MatheusSolha I have modified my answer. please check

Comment: You will need to implement different backend for this. The question was about getting port of the local dev server.